# Build a go application that uses GORM, In a github workflow

Tags: go, github-actions, go-gorm, cgo

I have a simple Go app that uses GORM (The boilerplate code from their site).
I'm trying to `go build` it in a workflow in github, which runs on `windows-latest`.
The built-in GCC compiler throws the following error, which I have had some time before:

`undefined reference to__imp___iob_func`

I do remember I had this same problem before on my local PC, and I switched to a 64 bit GCC from MSYS2 and then it worked.
How do I solve this on the workflow? What actions do I write?

Edit: Just noticed I forgot to mention that I also have this issue with a `WailsApp` app. If this has a different solution (since I can't change the build command), would love to hear.

Comment: have you tried go build with `-a` option? `go build -a`

Comment: Related GitHub issue: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/57455

Answer (score 0):

Well, the solution was actually simpler than I thought.
I was using go1.18, and all I had to do was change it to go1.20 and it fixed it.

(though must say, didn't find any place that addressed this as a version problem. would love a link to it if someone knows of).